# Wrong related page in Wagtail CMS

Tags: python, django, django-models, content-management-system, wagtail

I've occurred with strange behaviour while constructing a blog using Wagtail CMS 1.3.1.

There is a case:

I have a page A that should has a relations to pages B and C

```
  B
 /
A
 \
  C
```

This's how my page's model looks like

```
# Post related page item    
class PostRelatedPage(models.Model):
    link_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name='+'
    )

    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('link_page')
    ]

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class PostRelatedPageItem(Orderable, PostRelatedPage):
    page = ParentalKey('core.PostPage', related_name='related_posts')


# Post page model
class PostPage(Page):
    ...

PostPage.content_panels = [
    ...
    InlinePanel('related_posts', label="Related posts"),
]
```

Ok, it looks correct.
But when I link to my page A related pages B and C, my page relates to itself

```
  A
 /
A
 \
  A
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is the exact incorrect behaviour you're seeing? (For example, is it displaying the wrong thing on the page template? If so, please post your template code.)

Comment: Yes it's displaying the wrong thing. My template code looks like: `code`{% for related in self.related_posts.all %}{{ related.page }}{% endfor %}. I think the issue in my template. May be I should access not to page but link_page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the code you're using to output the links:

```
{% for related in self.related_posts.all %}{{ related.page }}{% endfor %}
```

Here `related` is a `PostRelatedPageItem` object, and `related.page` points back to the page it's attached to. You should use `related.link_page` instead.